# Do their exist geometric sequences where no element is congruent to the first element modulo m?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

Here, I am talking about sequences where the factor of multiplication is $k^m$ and the first term is also $k^m$ like:

$$k^m, k^{2m}, k^{3m}, \cdots \pmod{m}$$

Is it possible that none of the elements after $k^m$ are congruent to $k^m \pmod{m}$? I don't think that this is possible for a prime $m$ since by Fermat's Little Theorem $k^m \equiv k$ and $k^{m^2} \equiv k^m \equiv k$. I am not so sure for other $m$. In all the cases I've tried till now, there always exists a power congruent to the first term. Also, could you please give examples of sequences if they exist.

Thanks.

Comment: Note: if $\gcd (k,m)=1$ then:  find natural numbers $i>j$ with $k^{im}\equiv k^{jm}\pmod m$ (always possible) and then remark that this implies $k^{(i-j)m}\equiv 1$ so $k^{(i-j+1)m}\equiv k^m$.

Answer (score 2):

Write $m=ab$ where $a$ is the greatest divisors of $m$ coprime to $k$.
For any $p\mid b$, if $p^r\mid m$ then certainly also $p^r\mid k^m$ (becasue $p\mid k$ and $m\ge r$). Hence $k^{im}\equiv 0\pmod b$ for all $i$.
Whereas $\gcd(k,a)=1$ implies that $k^m$ is invertible $\bmod a$, hence the sequence is periodic. So for suitable $i>1$, we have $k^{im}\equiv k^m\pmod a$. As also $k^{im}\equiv k^m\pmod b$ and $\gcd(a,b)=1$, we indeed have $k^{im}\equiv k^m\pmod m$.